# how to use nuxtjs with laravel?

Tags: laravel, nuxtjs

I created api's in laravel and I want to send requests to laravel backend through nuxtjs frontend,
in laravel authentication I'm using laravel passport and I'm not using oath2, my first question is, what are the steps on laravel side to make it accepts requests from nuxtjs frontend?
second,
I have read in nuxtjs documentation [here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-passport/) how to authenticate with laravel passport using axios.

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    'laravelPassport': {
      provider: 'laravel/passport',
      endpoints: {
        userInfo: '...'
      },
      url: '...',
      clientId: '...',
      clientSecret: '...'
    },
  }
}
```

what can I put as `userInfo`?

what should the `url` be? is it the same as my localhost domain for laravel?
is this way only for login? but what about other api requests how can I trigger them from nuxt?

Answer (score 0):

first of all gotta say as laravel itself says:

> If your application absolutely needs to support OAuth2, then you
> should use Laravel Passport.

since you are not using auth2, better to switch to [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum).

url is the url to your backend (the url serving laravel).
userInfo is the endpoint for getting user info after logging in, I'm not sure about passport but in sanctum it is the url for your laravel route, returning user data using api token.

example for endpoints:

```
endpoints: {
   login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post' },
   logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
   user: { url: '/auth/user', method: 'get' }
}
```

Comment: thanks, supposing I'm using oauth2 on laravel, should I do something else on laravel for connection with nuxtjs or all I have to do is just whats in the nuxt side documentation above?

Comment: @AIB you most definitely have to do more stuff on laravel side, cause it's using oAuth2 and you have to handle everything on the laravel side, Nuxt Auth is only a middleman. I cannot give anymore info cause I myself never have used oAuth2 before. if you want to switch to Sanctum, I can assist further.